# Auth0 error:access denied;error_description=Invalid thumbprint

Tags: angular, saml, auth0

I have implemented Auth0 for saml sso integration in angular.
Its working fine and redirecting me to IDP server but after successful login, it redirects me to my angular site with an error as: error_description=Invalid thumbprint 
I have configured a service

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: '*********************',
    domain: 'samlsso.auth0.com',
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: 'https://samlsso.auth0.com/userinfo',
    redirectUri: 'domain-name/user-profile/',
    scope: 'openid'
  });
```

Response is
    http://domain-name/user-profile/#error=access_denied&error_description=Invalid%20thumbprint%20(configured%3A%208897ABDEE6B39613F3DF3DE8B1503E43F7C49E0F.%20calculated%3A%20384CD4243949BB1495ED5808E839B28204D9B1FD)&state=2ZyXEtgYp7bsHbN8JYwNDY3JT9KltYpk

Please help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set up "Allowed Callback URLs" in Auth0 Application setting?

Comment: Yes @VaibhavBhavsar same as 'domain-name/user-profile/'
Is it right?

Comment: yes @Priyal Agrawal

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?